# Scrolling to bottom not working in android browser

Tags: android, jquery

hi actually im facing a strange problem the problem only apear in the default browser of my android phone but work fine in all desktop browser and all other mobile browser.

what i am doing is i trigger the div to scroll to bottom on load. it work fine but not in android default browser here is my code

```
$("#divtoscroll").scrollTop($("#divtoscroll")[0].scrollHeight);
```

on all other browser that work very well but on that android default browser it scroll but to the top insteed of the bottom any advice ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19625

Seems, you should either don't use the stock Android browser or use some ugly workarounds.